# android folders problem. please help me

Tags: micromax

Am using micromax unite 2 a106 device
Am used the app 'folder mount' for move files to sd card for the apps whatsapp,uc dowloads,picsart,and other apps.
After some days my phone having many hang problemz.
I just uninstalled foldermount and did a hard reset to my phone. But before uninstalling folder mount i forgot to unmount all folders.
Now i am facing many problemz with that.
The folder mount partitions stil in my phone.
If i create a folder "whatsapp" to my sd card and internal storrage. The folders mounting automatically. And afte 1 or 2 minutes phone will hang up. I formatted sd card but it is not a solution. Am tried another sd card. But the result is same. 
How i remove these folder partition????
Helpe guysssss.
Thankss in adwance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This could not happen if you have hard reset the device. But still you can try Installing 'folder mount' again and unmount all partition created on sdcard. 
If this not work you can always flash the stock firmware to restore the device.